# Change payment method string to translatable string

Tags: magento-1, payment-methods, localisation

The `template > checkout > onepage > payment > methods.phtml` file outputs the payment method string that is shown in the onepage checkout of Magento 1.9.

It's very weird that this string is not translatable by default: 
I changed lines 81 to 87 from this:

```
<label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>">
        <?php if ( isset($payment_map[$_code]) ) : ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $payment_logos_url . $payment_map[$_code] . $payment_logos_filetype; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>" /><?php break; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </label>
```

To this:

```
<label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>">
        <?php if ( isset($payment_map[$_code]) ) : ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $payment_logos_url . $payment_map[$_code] . $payment_logos_filetype; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>" /><?php break; ?>
        <?php else : ?>

// changed line
                <?php echo $this->__($this->escapeHtml($title)) ?> <?php echo $this->__($this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method)) ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
        </label>
```

Is this something that should be default in Magento 1.9? If yes, should I make a pull request in the Magento 1.9 repo (if this is possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had a penny every time I found a bug in Magento... To reply to your question, I don't think this is really an issue. If you check this method, it loads a block object that you can define for a custom payment gateway (I haven't found any for default methods, so it's optional).

The translation would then happen *within* this block's template, so you only pass on pieces of text, and it doesn't get mixed up with HTML tags